# how can I set session id and verify on the next page in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to set session id using pin column my query result and check to see whether the session was set to that value on the next page, Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once('AppLogin_Class.php');
$success='';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$pin=$_POST['SIDN'];
$status=0;
try{
        require_once('connection.php');

        $message='Invalid Application Pin';
        $STH=$db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pins WHERE pin=? && status=?");
        $STH->bindParam(1,$pin);
        $STH->bindParam(2,$status);
        $STH->execute();
        $row=$STH->fetch();
        if($STH->rowCount()==1){
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['pin'];;

            echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="=1;applicants/upload_pass.php?pin=$pin"/> ';
        }else{
            return $message;
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Here is my next page verification code

```
<?php
$pin=$_GET['pin'];
require_once('class_applicants.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="=1;../appHome.php"/> ';
}else{
//success page here
}?>
```

Someone should help me to check while the page is loging me out because of session id

Comment: Make sure, you are calling session_start() on every page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `session_start()`;

Example:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $pin=$_GET['pin'];
  require_once('class_applicants.php');
   if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="=1;../appHome.php"/> ';
  }else{
  //success page here
    }?>
```

and also

```
<?php
  session_start();
require_once('AppLogin_Class.php');
 $success='';
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$pin=$_POST['SIDN'];
 $status=0;
 try{
    require_once('connection.php');

    $message='Invalid Application Pin';
    $STH=$db_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pins WHERE pin=? && status=?");
    $STH->bindParam(1,$pin);
    $STH->bindParam(2,$status);
    $STH->execute();
    $row=$STH->fetch();
    if($STH->rowCount()==1){
        $_SESSION['id']=$row['pin'];;

        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="=1;applicants/upload_pass.php?pin=$pin"/> ';
    }else{
        return $message;
    }
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st :** Start the session both page on top of the page

```
 session_start();
```

**2nd :** Instead of meta tag . just use header function.

```
 <?php
     session_start();
    $pin=$_GET['pin'];
    require_once('class_applicants.php');
    if(empty($_SESSION['id'])){
        header('Location:../appHome.php');
        exit();
    }else{
    //success page here
    }
  ?>
```

**Note :** Header function doesn't stop the code execution so you need to use exit() after header function .